# How to generate response objects with OpenAPI generator

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am using [OpenApiTools generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate java code from my openAPI specification files.

For all **components: schemas** models are being generated.

I would also like to generate **components: responses** as models.

```
components:
    responses:
        CreateOperationResponse:    // <-- This model is not generated as class
            description: >-
                The sample data
            content:
                application/hal+json:
                    schema:
                        allOf:
                            - $ref: '.CommonDefinitions.yaml#/components/schemas/ResponseStatus'
                            - $ref: '#/components/responses/SchemaDefinition'
    schemas:
        SchemaDefinition:           // <-- This model is generated as class
            description: This is a sample schema definition
            type: string
```

I see this is the parsed OpenAPI specification that [CodegenConfigurator.java](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/config/CodegenConfigurator.java#L618) generates
[image]

Is there a way I can configure OpenAPI generator to also generate responses as models form specification?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but `- $ref: '#/components/responses/SchemaDefinition'` is not valid inside `allOf`. `allOf` can only contain schemas and cannot contain other component types (responses, parameters, etc.).